# Error when installing another ruby version using rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, linux-mint

I am trying to install ruby  1.9.3 but I am getting this error.

```
✘ sushant@sushant-Vostro-3900   rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p125
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.0'.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: mint/17/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p125.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for mint.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/sushant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9505k  100 9505k    0     0   103k      0  0:01:31  0:01:31 --:--:--  164k
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p125 to /home/sushant/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125 - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #applying patch /home/sushant/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
showing last 15 lines of /home/sushant/.rvm/log/1456220961_ruby-1.9.3-p125/make.log
     OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(SSLv3_client),
                           ^
ossl_ssl.c:106:69: note: in definition of macro ‘OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY’
 #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                     ^
make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sushant/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125/ext/openssl'
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling callback-8.c
linking shared-object dl/callback.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sushant/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125/ext/dl/callback'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sushant/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I have googled a lot for this and none of the solution seem to work for me. This is my current setup

I am running linux mint 17 32 bit. My ruby and rvm version is `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [i686-linux]` , `rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

Comment: You are porbably missing one or other shared library - in this case it may be openssl.

Comment: More information may be in `/home/sushant/.rvm/log/1456220961_ruby-1.9.3-p125/make.log`.

Comment: @froderik, openssl is already the latest version. and i took a look at the make.log file and I did not find anything helpful there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you gone through [this thread](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/834)?

You might need to install this [patch](https://gist.github.com/mislav/055441129184a1512bb5), to skip `SSLv3`.
Check [this comment](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/834#issuecomment-160627207)

```
curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/mislav/055441129184a1512bb5.txt | rbenv install --patch <RUBY_VERSION>
```

in case if you are using rvm, you could use (based on this [comment](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3529#issuecomment-157205030))

```
curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/mislav/055441129184a1512bb5.txt > no_sslv3.patch
```

then execute below command

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --patch ./no_sslv3.patch
```

Comment: i am using rvm so I guess that wont help

Comment: Did you check this? https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3529? Any way, you need to add patch to skip the SSLV3 version.

Comment: `rvm install 1.9.3 --patch ./no_sslv3.patch ` i got this err  `There has been an error applying the specified patches. Halting the installation.`

Comment: Have you ran this command `git show 801e1fe46d83c856 > no_sslv3.patch`, before trying that?

Comment: should I run that in my working directory or outside of it?

Comment: i ran it outside and inside my working directory and both did not work.

Comment: You need to checkout ruby repository and run it. Check this comment, https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3529#issuecomment-157205030

Comment: ok i got it working. thanks for your help. This is what I did though `curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/mislav/055441129184a1512bb5.txt > no_sslv3.patch` then `rvm install 1.9.3 --patch ./no_sslv3.patch`

Comment: is it possible to upate your answer?